# WebGL Globe not rendering with OS and Chrome upgrade

Tags: google-chrome, graphics, webgl, macos-sierra, webgl-globe

I've been developing with the WebGL Chrome globe: https://www.chromeexperiments.com/globe

Everything was working fine until I recently upgraded my operating system to macOS Sierra, and also updated Google Chrome.  Now I do not see the globe in the browser, and instead get a message: "Sorry, your graphics card doesn't support WebGL"

This was working fine before I upgraded the OS and Chrome.

Why would it not work now?  My system is using the same graphics card as before, but now it does not support WebGL?  Seems more like a software issue.

Anyone have any insights into how to resolve this?

Comment: hardware acceleration is already set to active in Chrome settings

Comment: try disabling gpu blacklist

Comment: Just be aware if the driver was blacklisted it was blacklisted for a reason. If possible it's best to update your drivers. I'm on macOS Sierra 10.12.4 on a mid 2015 MBP. You?

Comment: @gman yes, i updated recently to macOS Sierra 10.12.4.  My laptop is circ 2010 or 2011, so perhaps the GPU hardware is on the edge.  anyway, since i disabled blacklist, so far so good ...

Answer (score 1):

yes, going to chrome://flags/ and enabling "Override software rendering list" fixed it

Comment: Because of localization/translation of these functions you probably want to link to the exact setting: chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blacklist